# How to add window.open event to the ZeroClipboard

Tags: javascript

i used ZeroClipboard to get the copy to the clipboard effect,now i want to copy and open site, so how to add the `window.open()` to the code. thank you. eg: the following is my customed js file.

```
ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath("js/ZeroClipboard.swf");.......
```

the html's structure is

```
<div id="test" link="the url will be open">text will be copied</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event listner - e.g. onMouseUp - to achive this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client(),
    myTextToCopy = "Hi, this is the text to copy!";                
    clip.glue('d_clip_button');
    clip.setText(myTextToCopy);

    clip.addEventListener('onMouseUp', eventFunction);

    function clipboardEvent() {
        window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
    }
</script>
```

I have not tested the code, so please let me know if you run into any further trouble ;)